# c# collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute while trying to remove from list

Tags: c#, sql

Hello for a project im using C# WPF applications in combination with SQL. 
However when trying to run some delete statements within the application I get the following error: "collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute". I've read on the internet and tried numerous solutions but none solved my problem.

**My code**

The SQL query that creates the list and fills the list with all orders

```
public List<ProductOrder> ProductOrders(int id)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(Database.StringGlenn);
        ProductOrder = new List<ProductOrder>();
        string query = "select po.OrderID, p.Naam, po.Aantal from ProductOrder as po inner join Product as p on po.ProductID = p.ProductID where po.OrderID ='" + id  + "'";
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        using (reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ProductOrder productorder = new ProductOrder();
                productorder.OrderId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["OrderID"]);
                productorder.Product = reader["Naam"].ToString();
                productorder.Aantal = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Aantal"]);
                ProductOrder.Add(productorder);
            }
        }
        con.Close();
        return ProductOrder;
    }
```

The delete query:

```
public void VerwijderOrder(int id)
    {
        con.Open();
        foreach (ProductOrder po in ProductOrder)
        {
            if (po.OrderId == id)
            {
                string query = "delete from [Order] where OrderID = " + id;
                cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                ProductOrder.Remove(po);
            }
        }
        con.Close();
```

The code on the delete button

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int orderId = Convert.ToInt32((DataOrders.SelectedItems[0] as Orders).OrderId);
                inter.VerwijderProductOrder(orderId);
                LaadOrders();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            }
        }
```

I've tried showing the query in a messagebox and it shows the right query so it should be working. However I keep getting this error.

Comment: Not a fix for your code, but a general observation. Using singular "productorder" for both the list and each item in the list is very confusing. Consider different names - `productOrderList` and `productOrder` for example.

Comment: Which line did the error get thrown on and what part of the error message are you having trouble understanding? It seems to say pretty clearly that you are trying to remove an item from a list while enumerating it and it should have pointed you at the exact line in question... Also when reporting errors you should always say exactly where the error is being thrown and not leave us guessing or having to search through loads of irrelevant code to find the spot.

Comment: Sorry I get the error in this line "foreach (ProductOrder po in ProductOrder)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is, that you remove an item from the list you iterate. Just remove the items later. Possibly like this:

```
public void VerwijderOrder(int id)
{
    List<ProductOrder> deletes = new List<ProductOrder>();
    con.Open();
    foreach (ProductOrder po in ProductOrder)
    {
         if (po.OrderId == id)
         {
              string query = "delete from [Order] where OrderID = " + id;
              cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
              deletes.Add(po);
         }
    }
    con.Close();

    deletes.forEach(d => ProductOrder.Remove(d));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not modify the collection inside the block when you are enumerating over it.

```
foreach (ProductOrder po in ProductOrder)
{
    ProductOrder.Remove(po); <-- this is causing your exception
}
```

The fix would be to remove it outside of the block. Here you can use [RemoveAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes a predicate.

```
public void VerwijderOrder(int id)
{
    // code not shown has not been altered
    foreach (ProductOrder po in ProductOrder)
    {
        if (po.OrderId == id)
        {
            // ProductOrder.Remove(po);
        }
    }
    ProductOrder.RemoveAll(x => x.OrderId == id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue, as explained in other answers is that you are removing items from the list you are iterating, but really you don't need a loop at all.

```
ProductOrder.RemoveAll(p=> p.OrderID == id);
```

Also

- [**ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS** use parameterised queries.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)
- Enclose unmanaged resources in `using` blocks to ensure they are properly disposed of.
- You never actually execute your command
- [There is no benefit to re-using SqlConnection, or Command objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9807317/1048425), I would suggest creating a new one each time

So your final code might end up as:

```
public void VerwijderOrder(int id)
{
    con.Open();
    string query = "delete from [Order] where OrderID = @id";
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    );
    ProductOrder.RemoveAll(p=> p.OrderID == id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant delete inside a `foreach` loop which enumerates the collection you want to delete from. This :

```
foreach (ProductOrder po in ProductOrders)
{
   if (po.OrderId == id)
    {
      string query = "delete from [Order] where OrderID = " + id;
      cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
      ProductOrders.Remove(po);
   }
}
```

Should be changed to this:

```
List<ProductOrder> ForRemovall=new List<ProductOrder>()
foreach (ProductOrder po in ProductOrders)
{
   if (po.OrderId == id)
    {
      string query = "delete from [Order] where OrderID = " + id;
      cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
      ForRemovall.Add(po);
   }
} 

foreach (ProductOrder po in ForRemoval)
{   
      ProductOrders.Remove(po);   
}
```

Comment: I believe a faster way would be to save not the items, but the indexes of those items in the list, then deleting the items at those indexes in reverse order (to preserve indexes). I'm not saying this to discredit your answer, since it is correct and adequate in most cases, but more like an idea for later exploration. When dealing with large lists it might be worth exploring every alternative for performance gains.

Comment: I used thi method but its somehow still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, I forgot the ExecutenonQuery code;

Final code:

```
public void VerwijderProductOrder(int id)
    {
        con.Open();
                string query = "delete from ProductOrder where OrderID = " + id;
                cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ProductOrder.RemoveAll(p => p.OrderId == id);
        con.Close();
    }
```